# AngularJS date filter not producing results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter

Currently I have the following binding in my view:

```
<p>{{claim.date}}</p>
```

Which contains something like this:

```
Oct 19, 2015 4:34:00 PM
```

I want to format it so that it displays like this:

```
Oct 19, 2015
```

Looking at all the AngularJS date filters I see that I need to do this:

```
<p>{{claim.date | date : 'mediumDate'}}</p>
```

However nothing is happening. Am I doing this right?

Comment: claim.date is date object or string..?

Comment: I just wanted to say that there is this amazing thing I use often: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.date = "Oct 19, 2015 4:34:00 PM";
  $scope.date2 = new Date("Oct 19, 2015 4:34:00 PM");
});

app.filter('stringToDate', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return new Date(input);
  };
});

app.filter('stringToDateFormat', function($filter) { 
  return function(input, format) { 
    return $filter("date")(new Date(input), format);
  }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div>
    {{date | stringToDate |date: "mediumDate"}}
  </div>
    <div>
    {{date | stringToDateFormat: "mediumDate"}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{date2 | date: "mediumDate"}}
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I can't instantiate a new javascipt date. It's a string variable I read from JSON

Comment: then do $scope.date = new Date(yourstring);, the date filter works on date objects

Comment: why not 
app.filter('stringToDate', function($filter) {
  return function(input, format) {
    return $filter("date")(new Date(input), format);
  };
});
then you can avoid use of date filter and use
{{date | stringToDate : "mediumDate"}}

Comment: @Kulbhushan added this idea to my answer :) Thx !
DeanGibson : Please see the edits I done to my original post and tell me if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet. It working fine for date object. Make sure that your object is `date object`, not `string`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>{{date}}</p>
  <p>{{date | date : 'mediumDate'}}</p>
</div>
```